# Groovy String Tokenizer matching on the wrong delimiter

Tags: java, regex, groovy, tokenize

I have a String that has values like this "inactiveCatalog%2CwrongTransaction", I want to bring this into a list breaking on the "%2C"....

```
String rseFiltersToRemove = "inactiveCatalog%2CwrongTransaction"
ArrayList rseFiltersToRemoveList = rseFiltersToRemove.tokenize("%2C")
```

I was expecting the list to have 2 elements ("inactiveCatalog" and "wrongTransaction"), but it turns out to have 3 ("inactive", "atalogItems" and "wrongTransaction").

So it thinks the "C" in "inactiveCatalog" is a delimiter.

How could this be when I set the delimiter to "%2C"?

Comment: Use `.split('%2C')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tokenize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method uses each character of a String as delimiter. So, `.tokenize("%2C")` splits on `%`, `2` and `C`.

Note that you do not get empty elements (that would be there in between `%` and and `2` and `C`) because `tokenize()` discards these empty strings when a delimiter appears twice in  succession.

You need `split()` that  takes the entire string as delimiter:

```
ArrayList rseFiltersToRemoveList = rseFiltersToRemove.split('%2C');
// => [inactiveCatalog, wrongTransaction]
```

See the [online Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/uOpZJF).

Answer (score 1):

[tokenize](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.0/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#tokenize(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) uses any of the delimiters, as per [StringTokenizer.tokenize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

You can simply use `split` with your string as delimiter:

```
groovy:000> 'inactiveCatalog%2CwrongTransaction'.split("%2C")
===> [inactiveCatalog, wrongTransaction]
```